# nextjs redirect works fine on local but does not work on production

Tags: reactjs, redirect, next.js

I have a next.config.js that looks like this:

```
module.exports = (phase, { defaultConfig }) => {
  const config = withFonts(
    withImages(
      withSass({
        publicRuntimeConfig: {
          CMS_HOST: process.env.CMS_HOST,
        },
        // trailingSlash: true,
        exportPathMap: function() {
          return {
            "/": { page: "/" }
          };
        },
        redirects: async function() {
          return [{
            source: '/team/:slug*',
            destination: '/about-us/:slug*',
            permanent: true,
          },{
            source: '/advance-rate-model',
            destination: '/financing-options',
            permanent: true,
          },{
            source: '/medical-lien-factoring',
            destination: '/financing-options',
            permanent: true,
          }]
        }
      })
    )
  )
  return config;
};
```

when I run on localhost:3000, it works fine, but when I deploy to stag and production, it does not redirect. Can someone please help? Thank you so much.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, do you mean you get a 404 instead of a redirect?

Comment: yes, it returns 404 and redirects to 404 page

Comment: I am using like this in next.config: module.exports = () => { const config= withFonts(withImages(withSass({redirects: async function(){...}})))}. I also edited my question

Comment: But how is your website deployed to production: do you export it as static HTML (`next build && next export`), or do you use `next build && next start`?

Comment: My guess is that you're probably exporting it as static HTML. The `redirects` config is not applied when using `next export` to deploy your Next.js app. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/export-no-custom-routes for details.

Comment: thank you so much @juliomalves, let me try

Comment: See this [feature request](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/17322) for upvoting when interested in this feature.

Comment: @juliomalves What's the possible fix for this issue without changing the `next build && next start`

Comment: @AdewaleOlaoye `redirects` requires a server to work, so you need `next build && next start`. The alternative is to handle the redirects outside the Next.js app, in the web server that serves the static pages.